# Is it possible to have multiple variables in the destination string of a feature?

Tags: installshield

I'm trying to future proof our InstallShield project against future name changes and am having issues with one feature I would like to use two IS variables to create the destination path.

Destination: **[CommonAppDataFolder][ProductName]Foo**

Previously, this feature was installed using only one variable and a static path including the product name.

Destination: [CommonAppDataFolder]Product Name\Foo

From the install log it looks like the second variable in the bolded string above wasn't expanded, C:\ProgramData\[ProductName]\Foo.  The installer also didn't create the folder structure for it, even though I am manually able to create it on the system, including the '[' and ']' characters.

Is there another way to do this dynamically so I don't have to remember the hard way when our customer inevitably changes our Product Name again?

Answer (score 0):

One technique to consider would be to use the InstallShield Automation Interface in conjunction with the Stand Alone Build.  You can set the ISM that gets checked into source control as something generic like My Company My Product.  Then at build time you can pump in these values and mutate the installer to some variant.

This is how we did it at my last job.  We built hundreds of installers branded as different companies and products all from a single ISM project that served as a foundation and all the details were built up around it at build time.